# Kendo ui Parent Child Passing Additional Parameter from within read

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have Parent Child kendo ui grids.

The child Grids read looks like this

```
read: {
        url: baseURL + "/GetOrgSchools/OrgID=" + window.SelectedOrg, 
       // data: { OrgID : window.SelectedOrg }, // pass aditional data
        dataType: "json" // <-- The default was "jsonp"
    },
```

I am able to filter the child records on the selection of Parent row using this

```
window.SelectedOrg = orgID;
            $("#gridOrgSchools").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read({ OrgID: orgID });
            $("#gridOrgSchools").css("display", "block");
```

But now the child grid has paging Filtering and sorting enabled.
so if I click the next page, it is not passing the `OrgID` and its value, it starts showing all the records.

What do I need to do so that on all the subsequent paging, filtering etc of child grid, i should be able to stick the OrgID in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data) function of the dataSource to constantly send to the server that field need. It will be automatically send with each server request the dataSource does.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the following in transport of kendou ui

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {


        if (operation == "read")
        {
            if (window.SelectedOrg != null)
                options.OrgID = window.SelectedOrg;
        }
```